# C# Prevent WP browser from opening Bing app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control, bing

I am trying to make a Windows Phone 8 web browser type application but my problem is that trying to use bing.com to display search results always opens the Bing search app. Now this is very helpful for users of the native browser because the Bing app then open the link in Internet Explorer but this is unfortunately very unhelpful on 3rd party browser. Is there any way to disable this and allow users to use Bing in my app or will they be forced to use google.

Comment: did you already check all parameters that you can pipe to the call? maybe one of the overloads contains something like (..., bool newWindow = true,...)

Comment: I have been through them all and none really stand out. I also don't want to disable this behavior completely because it also launches thing like the app store which is quite handy.

Comment: Are you using native WebBrowser control of WP8 to render web pages?

Comment: @RiteshKhichadia yes I am

Comment: Then I think what you want is not possible, because native WebBrowser is designed as such. For e.g. if you open a store link to an app, internet explorer always opens native store client rather than opening the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround to inhibit this behavior by checking if its a search request for bing in Navigating event handler, then navigating to the same url with custom User Agent header.

Here's the code

```
private bool _customHeaderRequest = false;

private void MainBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    string host = e.Uri.Host.ToLowerInvariant().Trim();

    if ((host == "bing.com" || host.EndsWith(".bing.com")) && !_customHeaderRequest)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            MainBrowser.Navigate(e.Uri, null,
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 710)\r\n"));

        _customHeaderRequest = true;
        return;
    }

    _customHeaderRequest = false;
}

private void MainBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _customHeaderRequest = false;
}
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988333/1335882

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control inside of your web app. This would be much better than sending the user off to the bing.com/maps consumer site. This would also give you a lot more power in terms of what you can do and customization. You can find documentation on this API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

Comment: Ok, your first line indicates other wise: "I am trying to make a Windows Phone 8 web browser type application"

Comment: Yes, the application is literally a "web browser" like internet explorer, not an HTML application repackaged as a Windows Phone one using the browser component

Comment: ok, well you can still use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control. It is meant to be used in web pages, and also works when embedded in a WP8 web browser app. But that's if you need maps. If you need other Bing services there are a number of different API's. You can find them documented here: http://dev.bing.com