# preventing auto launching Bing search app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Any idea of how to disable auto-launching the Bing search app inside my application?

I have a WebView and it navigates to Bing search but it automatically redirect the user to the Bing search app which is not suitable for me, I want to disable it.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988333/815938) works for you.